# How to replicate the predict function from R in Excel given I have access to "summary" output from R

Tags: r, excel, regression, predict, mse

I have run a 3rd order polynomial regression in R and have run the "summary" function, but I need to be able to replicate the "predict" function in Excel. I have my current working code below. Thank you for your help!

```
#Have access to this output:
AICFit <- lm(R60 ~ poly(M20, 3) + poly(M40, 3), data = mydata)
summary(AICFit)

#do not have access to output: 
predict(AICFit,data.frame(M20=0.972375241,M40=0.989086129,interval ="prediction")
```

Basically, I don't have access to R when I have access to these numbers: 0.972375241,0.989086129.

I believe this is the equation that is the basis for the predict function, but I don't know how to compute this in Excel incorporating order 1, 2 and 3:
[image]

Comment: what do you mean you don't have access to R when you have those numbers? Also, you need to include your data by typing `dput(head(mydata))` and adding the output to your question. It is hard to help you without a reproducible example

Comment: You can read the Excel parameters in R, otherwise you have to get the coefficients of `AICFIT` and compute the calculation of your model with fitted values of coefficients

Answer (score 0):

You do not have enough information from `summary` to calculate the prediction interval in Excel.

So the simple answer is - it is not possible to do it without an access to variance-covariance matrix (however for orthogonal polynomials in your model it is diagonal) and raw data. Moreover you need to extract orthogonal polynomial coefficients themselves, which are generated recursively and uniquely for each dataset you are fitting.

The formula you are referencing is for the univariate linear regression and it is not applicable for your case where you are doing multivariate polynomial regression for two variables: `M20` and `M40`.